# I am unable to store a textview string into Sqlite Database in Android . below is my code of DatabaseHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite

DatabaeHelper.class

this is a common class. but i am unable to insert a value and get a data back from the database.

```
         public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
         private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pharmabarcode.db";
         private static final String TABLE_NAME = "pbstable";
         private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
         private static final String KEY_NAME = "result";

         public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
         super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.openOrCreateDatabase("pharmabarcode.db", null);
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST"+ TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String result){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, result);
    long rslt = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(rslt == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
public Cursor getAllData(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME,null );
    return res;
}}
```

this is the code of mainactivity to insert value in database

```
    try {
        boolean isInserted = mydb.insertData(barcodeValue.getText().toString());
        if (isInserted = true)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception occures",""+e);
    }
```

and this is my stack trace which says there is no table

```
    12-10 11:30:35.553 3158-3158/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                               Process: com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader, PID: 3158
                                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.HistoryActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: pbstable (code 1): , while compiling: select * from pbstable
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:176)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
                                                                                                Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: pbstable (code 1): , while compiling: select * from pbstable
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1285)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.DatabaseHelper.getAllData(DatabaseHelper.java:53)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.HistoryActivity.onCreate(HistoryActivity.java:30)
                                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6005)
                                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555) 
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:176) 
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437) 
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956) 
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Answer (score 3):

You logcat

```
.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: pbstable (code 1): , while compiling: select * from pbstable
```

It's because **Create Tale SQL Command** is wrong. 
You should add `white space` between `Column Type` and `Column Name`

I have added one more white space at this - "CREATE TABLE "

```
 String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response dear, but the problem is still there and stack trace remains same @M D

Comment: the logcat points to the cursor and says there is no such table available like this                                                                                                                  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: pbstable (code 1): , while compiling: select * from pbstable
                                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Comment: You might create this table after the DB file creation, try to uninstall and reinstall your app and check the logcat again

Comment: Ya if you changes database or table field you have to remove database  or app first and again install app.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done all the things. error disappears now but the data is not getting inserted because i have placed a Toast after the insertion but it is not Toasting!!!   @M D

Comment: Change your `CREATE_TABLE ` like answer ,it works on my device.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line `db.openOrCreateDatabase("pharmabarcode.db", null);`;
Uninstall  and reinstall your app again.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I have done all the things. error disappears now but the data is not getting inserted because i have placed a Toast after the insertion but it is not Toasting!!!